# Is there a way to pass arguments/options to pipeline-executed script?

Tags: bash, arguments, pipeline

We know may make following in bash:

```
curl -Ls example.com/script.sh | bash
```

But can we pass some arguments?

```
curl -Ls example.com/script.sh | bash --option1
```

In this case `bash` will take the option. May there some approach to pass it to the script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what the `-s` option is for:

```
curl -Ls example.com/script.sh | bash -s -- --option1
```

Since `-s` explicitly tells `bash` to read its commands from standard input, it doesn't try to interpret its first argument as a file from which to read commands. Instead, all arguments are used to set the positional parameters.

Alternatively, you can use a process substitution instead of reading directly from standard input.

```
bash <(curl -Ls example.com/script.sh) --option1
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. For me, works only last one. I've tested in "git bash" only so far. Anyway it's needed a cross-platform solution.

Comment: I'm not sure why the first one wouldn't work with git bash, although your version of git bash may use a very old version of bash.

Comment: I forgot the `--` argument, which is required to prevent `bash1 from treating `--option1` as an option whether or not `-s` is used.

Answer (score 1):

You could do:

```
( echo 'set -- --option1' && curl -Ls example.com/script.sh ) | bash
```

to prepend a `set` command the input.